# Dynamic Schema field in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema in which I'm storing a relationship between two users. Each of these relationships has user specific data. I'm curious as to if it's possible to do something along the lines of THIS:

```
{
    users: Array, 
    users[0]: {
        typing: Boolean,
        last_checked: Date
    },
    users[1]: {
        typing: Boolean,
        last_checked: Date
    }
}
```

Instead of having the information stored like so:

```
{
    users: Array,
    data: Array
}
```

and doing logic on the server to find the index, etc Like so:

```
 entry.data[entry.users.indexOf(id)].typing
```

Basically just trying to find a decent way to store user based information for each user in the 2-person relationship. **The most ideal situation to me would be to use the users `_id` as a key, but can you do that with Mongoose?**

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to create an array that's gonna contains user's data. Here I did restrained the size of the array to two relationships.

```
    DataSchema = {
       typing: Boolean,
       last_checked: Date,
    }

    UserSchema = {
       relationship: {
          type: [DataSchema],
          validate: [
             () => val.length <= 2,
            '{PATH} exceeds the limit of 2 relationship',
          ],
       }
    }
```

Access the data:

```
// User 1 data
entry.relationship[0]

// User 2 data
entry.relationship[1]

// User 1 _id you can use
entry.relationship[0]._id
```